# Difference between installation of flutter via Flutter Zip bundle and Flutter repo on github?

Tags: android, windows, flutter

what is the difference between  installation of flutter via Flutter Zip bundle and Flutter repo on github?

for zip file

[image]

For github repo

[image]

Which one will be better and what are difference between both?

Answer (score 1):

With git

- You can make changes to the code temporarily and you can checkout the changes later.
- You don't have to redownload everything next time new flutter version releases. You can git pull (if on stable branch).
- You can checkout to specific flutter versions.

With Windows:

- You don't need git installed in your system.

In my opinion, having flutter sdk with git makes more sense. Using some version manager like fvm (https://fvm.app/) is even more efficient as it handles multiple framework versions as well as update flutter is much easy.

Comment: Oh thank you for responding